# MySQL NOW() query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM ps_specific_price WHERE 'to' > NOW() ORDER BY `to` DESC
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM ps_specific_price WHERE 'to' > CURDATE() ORDER BY `to` DESC
```

The date in the 'to' field are like this: 2014-07-31 23:59:59

There is only one row where the 'to' is larger than now() but anyway the query returns the entire table (all the 1287 rows of the table). Where did I go wrong with theses queries?

Comment: Which data type does the `to` column have and what does `'to'` mean? the string `'to'`? or the value of the column `to`? Or do you actually have a column in the table named `'to'` (with the quotes)?

Comment: @ConradFrix I asked the same, but I actually expect it to be a string.

Comment: `to` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)  reserved words must be quoted with backticks (\`), not `'`. using `'` turns them into strings. `'to' > '2014-07-22 12:34:45'` will always be true.

Comment: 'to' is the value of the column 'to'.

Comment: no. `'to'` is a string with the letters `t` and `o`. `to` by itself is a reserved word and not directly usable in a query. `\`to\`` would be a field named `to`, because it's got proper backtick escapes. consider `select select from select where select=update`. total nonsense, but if you write is ``select `select` from `select` where `select`=`update` `` it becomes a valid (and very ugly) query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_specific_price WHERE `to` > NOW() ORDER BY `to` DESC
```

using backticks and not quotes

Comment: first query is wrong. `to` is a reserved word, so that query is a flat-out syntax error. second one is the only acceptable format.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  If it doesn't work, then please `DESC ps_specific_price`

Answer (score 1):

you have used wrong quotation ,, you need to use  grave accent (`)
grave accent is use for mysql field and table

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_specific_price` WHERE `to` > CURDATE() ORDER BY to DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
  SELECT * FROM ps_specific_price WHERE DATE(to) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY to DESC
```